# How to set auto-deletion revisions in Google Docs List API?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Google Drive stores previous revisions of documents, which is great for going back in time. You can select whether the previous revisions are stored in using the Google Drive web interface:
http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375120

Is it possible to do this via the API or by changing some document property?

I've checked the revision feed, but see nothing there. Looking through the JSON I see a document property called "blob_versionable". Is there an API to set this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `pinned` field of a revision to true to prevent Google from automatically purging that revision:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-revisions

Comment: btw that only applies to Non-Google docs files . https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions#resource